# How to automate custom function to multiple rows?

Tags: r, function

I have created a function like the following

```
DI <- function(W=W, V=V, Ci=Ci, Cf=Cf, Cf_Des=Cf_Des, Vres=Vres, 
               Vfinal=Vfinal, onebyn_ads=onebyn_ads) {
  Ads <- (Ci - Cf)*(V/W)
  Cf_D1 <- Cf_Des[[1]]
  Ci_D1 <- max(Cf, na.rm=T)/(Vfinal/Vres)
  Des1 <- (Cf_D1 - Ci_D1)*(Vfinal/W)  
  Ads_D1 <- max(Ads, na.rm=T) - Des1
  Cf_D2 <- Cf_Des[[2]]
  Ci_D2 <- Cf_D1/(Vfinal/Vres)
  Des2 <- (Cf_D2 - Ci_D2)*(Vfinal/W)
  Ads_D2 <- Ads_D1 - Des2
  Cf_D3 <- Cf_Des[[3]]
  Ci_D3 <- Cf_D2/(Vfinal/Vres)
  Des3 <- (Cf_D3 - Ci_D3)*(Vfinal/W)
  Ads_D3 <-  Ads_D2 - Des3
  Cf_D4 <- Cf_Des[[4]]
  Ci_D4 <- Cf_D3/(Vfinal/Vres)
  Des4 <- (Cf_D4 - Ci_D4)*(Vfinal/W)
  Ads_D4 <- Ads_D3 - Des4  
  Ads_Des <- c(Ads_D1, Ads_D2, Ads_D3, Ads_D4)
  log_Cf_Des <- log10(Cf_Des)
  log_Ads_Des <- log10(Ads_Des)
  fit.slr <- lm(log_Ads_Des ~ log_Cf_Des)
  a <- 10^coef(fit.slr)[[1]]
  onebyn <- coef(fit.slr)[[2]]
  DI <- onebyn_ads/onebyn
  return(list(a=a, onebyn=onebyn, DI=DI))
}
```

The function is running fine for a dataset having 4 rows like

```
DI(W=2, V=20, Ci=df$Initial_conc, Cf=df$Equilibrium_conc, 
   Cf_Des=df$Cf_Des, Vres= 5, Vfinal=20, onebyn_ads=0.2056263)
```

Now you can see in the function that from `Cf_D1` to `Cf_D4`, rowwise subsetting of `Cf_Des` is done upto 4th row. Suppose someone is having more than 4 rows in their data, then it will not calculate correctly. How can I make it run for any number of rows of data?
Here is the example data

```
df <- structure(list(Initial_conc = c(10, 20, 40, 60), Equilibrium_conc = c(0.61958938580799, 
1.63333333333333, 17.27814490161, 35.1896333333333), Cf_Des = c(13.6284722222222, 
7.47767857142857, 6.0515873015873, 4.83630952380952)), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the calculation is initialized on `Cf_D1`. After doing this, use a `for` loop of 2 to NROW iterations.

```
DI2 <- function(W=W, V=V, Ci=Ci, Cf=Cf, Cf_Des=Cf_Des, Vres=Vres, 
                Vfinal=Vfinal, onebyn_ads=onebyn_ads) {
  ## ini
  Ads <- (Ci - Cf)*(V/W)
  Ads_Des <- numeric(length(Cf_Des))
  Ci_x <- max(Cf, na.rm=T)/(Vfinal/Vres)
  Ads_Des[[1]] <- Ads_x <- max(Ads, na.rm=T) - (Cf_Des[[1]] - Ci_x)*(Vfinal/W)
  ## loop
  for (i in seq_along(Cf_Des)[-1]) {
    Des_x <- (Cf_Des[[i]] - Cf_Des[[i - 1]]/(Vfinal/Vres))*(Vfinal/W)
    Ads_Des[[i]] <- Ads_x <- Ads_x - Des_x
  }
  ## processing
  log_Cf_Des <- log10(Cf_Des)
  log_Ads_Des <- log10(Ads_Des)
  fit.slr <- lm(log_Ads_Des ~ log_Cf_Des)
  a <- 10^coef(fit.slr)[[1]]
  onebyn <- coef(fit.slr)[[2]]
  DI <- onebyn_ads/onebyn
  return(list(a=a, onebyn=onebyn, DI=DI))
}

with(df, DI2(W=2, V=20, Ci=Initial_conc, Cf=Equilibrium_conc, 
   Cf_Des=Cf_Des, Vres= 5, Vfinal=20, onebyn_ads=0.2056263))
# $a
# [1] 27.26784
# 
# $onebyn
# [1] 0.7923875
# 
# $DI
# [1] 0.2595022
```

The results of `DI` and `DI2` are equal for original data frame `df`:

```
stopifnot(all.equal(with(df, DI(W=2, V=20, Ci=Initial_conc, Cf=Equilibrium_conc, 
                       Cf_Des=Cf_Des, Vres= 5, Vfinal=20, onebyn_ads=0.2056263)), 
          with(df, DI2(W=2, V=20, Ci=Initial_conc, Cf=Equilibrium_conc, 
                       Cf_Des=Cf_Des, Vres= 5, Vfinal=20, onebyn_ads=0.2056263))
          ))
```

Now using arbitrary number of rows in `df2`:

```
with(df2, DI2(W=2, V=20, Ci=Initial_conc, Cf=Equilibrium_conc, 
             Cf_Des=Cf_Des, Vres= 5, Vfinal=20, onebyn_ads=0.2056263))
# $a
# [1] 178.621
# 
# $onebyn
# [1] 0.3131333
# 
# $DI
# [1] 0.6566735
```

**Note,** that by using `with` you can avoid specifying `df$` when calling the funtion.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(Initial_conc = c(10, 20, 40, 60), Equilibrium_conc = c(0.61958938580799, 
1.63333333333333, 17.27814490161, 35.1896333333333), Cf_Des = c(13.6284722222222, 
7.47767857142857, 6.0515873015873, 4.83630952380952)), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(Initial_conc = c(10L, 20L, 40L, 60L, 80L, 100L, 
120L), Equilibrium_conc = c(0.6195894, 1.6333333, 17.2781449, 
35.1896333, 55.1896333, 85.1896333, 115.1896333), Cf_Des = c(13.628472, 
7.477679, 6.051587, 4.83631, 3.83631, 2.83631, 1.83631)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could include a loop in your function:

```
DI <- function(W=W, V=V, Ci=Ci, Cf=Cf, Cf_Des=Cf_Des, Vres=Vres, Vfinal=Vfinal, onebyn_ads=onebyn_ads) {
Ads <- (Ci - Cf)*(V/W)
Ads_Des <- c()
for (k in 1:length(Cf)){

  Cf_D1 <- Cf_Des[[k]]
  Ci_D1 <- max(Cf, na.rm=T)/(Vfinal/Vres)
  Des1 <- (Cf_D1 - Ci_D1)*(Vfinal/W)  
  Ads_D1 <- max(Ads, na.rm=T) - Des1
  Ads_Des <- append(Ads_Des, Ads_D1)
}

log_Cf_Des <- log10(Cf_Des)
log_Ads_Des <- log10(Ads_Des)
fit.slr <- lm(log_Ads_Des ~ log_Cf_Des)
a <- 10^coef(fit.slr)[[1]]
onebyn <- coef(fit.slr)[[2]]
DI <- onebyn_ads/onebyn
return(list(a=a, onebyn=onebyn, DI=DI))
}
```

Example with 5 rows:

```
df <- structure(list(Initial_conc = c(10, 20, 40, 60, 70), 
                 Equilibrium_conc = c(0.61958938580799,  1.63333333333333, 17.27814490161, 35.1896333333333, 40.5), 
                 Cf_Des = c(13.6284722222222, 7.47767857142857, 6.0515873015873, 4.83630952380952, 9.78)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Call your function:

```
DI(W=2, V=20, Ci=df$Initial_conc, Cf=df$Equilibrium_conc, Cf_Des=df$Cf_Des, Vres= 5, Vfinal=20, onebyn_ads=0.2056263)
```

Comment: I want to do calculate it for all the rows at time. So, argument `n` is not necessary.

Comment: True, you can get the length from argument Cf, see my edited answer.

Comment: Using your function I am not getting the desired output. The desired output is a = 27.26784, onebyn = 0.7923875, DI = 0.2595022 for the data provided in my question.